# How to get file as FormData when knowing its File URI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm sending images/file within form data to a rest api and i was able to send the data using code like this before when the user had selected a file:

```
 var data = new FormData(); 
 var files = $("#file-select").get(0).files;
 data.append('imgfile', files[0]);
```

However i now got some new code that enables me to get the File URI so i cant use the #file-select to get the file anymore.

My question is now: How can i use my File URI to send my file as form data something similar to above?

Any help or input highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This doesn't answer your question exactly, but this should get you started: https://gist.github.com/fesor/20d35041c14faacaccaa

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The File API can only access user selected files.

Access to files by a name provided by the application is forbidden for security reasons.